# JK Flip Flop Counter

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop

I am designing a counter circuit that will perform the following function:

A sequential circuit with three flip-flips A, B and C and two inputs X and Y.
If X=0 and Y=0, the counter remains in the same sate. 
If X=0 and Y=1, the circuit goes through the state transition from 000, 001, 010, 011,100,101, 110, 111, back to 000, and repeats.
If X=1 and Y=0, the circuit goes through the state transition from 111, 110, 101, 100, 011, 010, 001, 000, back to 111, and repeats.
If X=1 and Y=1, the counter reset to 000.

I'm a little confused about the two inputs 01 and 10, and how to account for the inputs to JK.

---

[image: State Table]

Comment: You will need a clock somewhere, else the outputs will never be stable.

Comment: This is just the State Table -- I don't think the clock needs to be included here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've gotten a little confused, I think. Your red entries should be for Jc/Kc. For the higher order bits A and B, and the current state 000, they remain at zero, and you use the same JK logic as you did for XY = 00 or 11.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. So, for instance, when ABC (present state) are 001, and XY = 01, Ja/Ka = 0X, Jb/Kb = 1X and Jc/Kc = X1..

The thing to remember here then is to only set the FlipFlop that is changing -- others leave it alone or reset it.

Comment: Yes, but additionally, if you want to change a bit, you can either force it (set or reset, whichever is appropriate) or toggle it (J and K both 1), and keep in mind that you can use your don't-cares to simplify the number of terms you need to generate the input.

Comment: How can we determine which flip-flop will work best?

Comment: Sorry? What are the choices, and what is your metric for "best"?

Comment: Yes, I suppose I should have been a little more specific. We've covered the JK, T, and D flip-flops only. By best, I mean low cost - maximum functionality. And in the world of electronic components, low cost generally means lower performance.

Comment: Not many products use discrete logic/flip-flops in any quantity, so cost isn't that big a concern. For large logic functions, it's usually done either in software on a microcontroller or microcomputer, or in hardware using FPGAs or CPLDs. In the latter case, the flip-flop type is chosen to make design easier, not for cost purposes (like going with a one-hot state machine, which is easiest to understand using D-types). Ultimately, any of the 3 types can be used for any sequential logic function - but the amount of support gates varies with the function and FF type.

Answer (score 0):

You are designing a synchronous 3-bit Up/Down counter using JK flip-flops.

http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/counter/count_4.html shows and explains such a counter.